# Close window after going to controller method in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

As soon as the user request for a specific method `close_method()` in controller `Close_Controller`, how to  make it close instead of render for a page?

I knew tricking in the view by adding javascript is work well, but is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about add this to your `Close_Controller` class :

```
function close_method(){
    echo  "<script type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "window.close();";
    echo "</script>";
}
```

Comment: sorry, forget to confirm

Answer (score 0):

not close with ?> codignater controller. 
Controller begins with
eg:

* @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
//not close with?>